# How to have two calendars in notification's bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, notifications, calendar, big-sur, widgets

Currently I have set my calendar to Persian and I have the calendar widget in notifications bar .

[image]

[image]

I was wondering If there is anyway to have two calendar widgets one showing the Persian calendar and the other showing the Gregorian calendar so I could know the date in both types ?

Comment: It seems like the only way that this might be possible would be to use a second calendar app that also has a widget and can be set independently of the system, such as Fantastical or BusyCal, but I have not tried that myself, so I cannot answer it directly. I believe Fantastical does have a free tier, so that would be the place to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a way to do this sadly there isn't anyway to get this done in macOS Big Sur.